# Retornar valor por json e retornar para uma função

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function novasMensagens(Alerta) {
  var retorno = Alerta > 0 ?  Alerta : "";
  return retorno;
}

document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = novasMensagens();
```

Agora pretendo retornar o valor de `Alerta` da função acima por ajax de uma consulta.

Ficheiro `php` onde faço a consulta:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(A.Alertas) AS Alerta
FROM(
SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, TIME_FORMAT(Recebido,'%h:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, centrodb.Alertas.Para, Status, Count(Status) AS Alertas FROM centrodb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.ValAlertas
ON centrodb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = centrodb.Alertas.Id AND centrodb.ValAlertas.Para = centrodb.Alertas.Para
WHERE centrodb.Alertas.Para = 'Pedro' 
Group BY Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, Recebido, Email, Tipo, centrodb.Alertas.Para, Status) AS A
WHERE A.Alertas = '0'
LIMIT 10";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
      echo json_encode($row);
```

Na função acima acrescentei o ajax da seguinte forma:

```
function novasMensagens(Alerta) {
  var retorno = Alerta > 0 ? Alerta : "";
  return retorno;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : './fetchbusca',
    success : function(data) {
     console.log(json);
    }
});
}

document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = novasMensagens();
```

Mas não retorna nada no `json`
O valor que vai retornar no `json`, tenho de o atribuir a `Alerta`, que está dentro da variável `retorno`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função possui erros que está impedindo de ser executada. Primeiro que você colocou um `return` antes da chamada `ajax`, isso fara que a função pare naquele `return` e nada abaixo dela vai ser executado. Segundo que eu sua `callback` você está esperando a variável data e no `console.log` está utilizando  a variável json. Faça as alterações:

```
function novasMensagens(Alerta) {
    var retorno = Alerta > 0 ? Alerta : "";
    //return retorno;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : './fetchbusca',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: era isso que precisava. Agora só tenho uma dúvida, o valor que é retornado dentro da função success, é atribuído acima ao `Alerta` que está dentro da variável `retorno`?

Comment: A menos que você faça essa atribuição dentro do success, não será atribuido

Comment: faço-o desta forma: `var Alerta = data;`

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa tarde!

Segue um exemplo utilizando uma requisição de servidor GET

Na função, você deve substituir a URL pelo caminho do método no seu controlador. (para exemplo: /api/Mensagens/Verificacao)

Exemplo:

DE

> url : 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/31030430/json/'

PARA:

> url : '/api/Mensagens/Verificacao'

Quando houver sucesso na busca do valor, a função irá escrever onde está indicado document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML.

Esse exemplo meu, eu faço uma busca por um CEP.

**MEU CASO**
Então, verifico que o cep que passei é de MG, se for eu retorno o campo ibge, se não for eu retorno "0".

**SEU CASO**
No seu caso, você vai olhar se o retorno é maior que 0, se for é porque tem novas mensagens e você então retorna o valor de mensagens 1, 2, 5... e será salvo esse número no document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML.

```js
function novasMensagens() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/31030430/json/',
    success : function(data) {
    data.uf === "MG" ? document.getElementById("msgNumero").innerHTML = data.ibge :
    document.getElementById("msgNumero").html = "0";
    console.log(data.uf);
    console.log(data.ibge);
    console.log(data.cep);
    },
    error: function(){
      document.getElementById("msgNumero").html = "ERRO"
    },    
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msgNumero"></div>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="novasMensagens();">Verificar novas mensagens</button>
```

Obs. Eu deixei três console-logs na função para ajudá-lo a ver os resultados que vem.

Pode mudar o CEP na função para você ver o que acontece.
O cep do exemplo é o 31030430